# Learning MySQL, Python - Skip Duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, python-2.7

I've been trying to learn SQL using python to update a db and am trying to do something simple. Iterate through a csv file that includes the fortune 500 with their revenue info and push into an SQL db. I've run it a few times and it's working great, the only issue is I'm getting duplicates because I've run the same file a few times.

In the future, I'm assuming it's good to learn how to avoid duplicates. After looking around this is what I've found for a proposed solution using WHERE NOT EXISTS but am getting an error. Any advice is welcome as I'm totally new.

Note - I do know I should be updating more than one row at a time, that's my next lesson

```
import pymysql
import csv

with open('companies.csv','rU') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for i in reader:

        conn = pymysql.connect(host='host', user='user', passwd='pw', db='db_test')
        cur = conn.cursor()

        query1 = "INSERT INTO companies (Name, Revenue, Profit, Stock_Price) VALUES (\'{}\',{},{},{})".format(str(i['Standard']),float(i['Revenues']),float(i['Profits']),float(i['Rank']))
        query2 = 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Name FROM companies WHERE Name = \'{}\')'.format(str(i['Standard']))
        query = query1+' '+query2

        cur.execute(query)
        conn.commit()
        cur.close()
```

OUTPUT:

```
INSERT INTO companies (Name, Revenue, Profit, Stock_Price) VALUES ('WalMart Stores',469.2,16999.0,1.0) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Name FROM companies WHERE Name = 'WalMart Stores')
```

ERROR:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Name FROM companies WHERE Name = 'WalMart Stores')' at line 1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. First of all, congratulations on self-learning!

Now, to the point.

When you use `insert ... values`, you can't define a where condition for the table on which you're inserting values. `insert` statement is only used to insert (When you use `insert... select`, you can define a `where` condition *on the select*, not on the table on which you're about to insert values).

So, there are two ways to do what you want:

1. Create a unique index on the column that you want to test, and then use `insert ignore...`
2. In your code, check if the value is already there, and if it's not, then insert it.

I'll tell you how to work with the first suggestion, because it'll teach you a couple of things. As for suggestion 2, I'll leave that for you as homework ;-)

First, you need to add a unique index to your table. If you want to avoid duplicates on the `Name` column, then:

```
alter table companies
    add unique index idx_dedup_name(Name);
```

[Check the syntax for `ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html).

And now, let's say that `Companies` already has a row with name `'XCorp'`. If you try a normal `INSERT... VALUES` statement here, you'll get an error, because you're trying to add a duplicate value. If you want to avoid that error, you can use something like this:

```
insert ignore into companies(name) values ('XCorp');
```

This will execute as a normal insert, but, since you're trying to insert a duplicate value, it will fail, but silently (it wil throw a warning instead of an error).

---

As for suggestion 2, as I told you, I leave it to you as homework.

Hints:

1. Count the rows where the name matches a value.
2. Read the count to a variable in your python program
3. Test the value... if there's zero entries, then perform the insert.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. It makes sense that I need to create a unique index, I should have thought of that. From a performance standpoint, which suggestion is preferred? It seems like option 2 would require more calls to the db, but I could definitely be wrong. Thanks again!

Comment: From a pure performance point of view, the unique index seems more efficient, because it delegates the responsability to the database server. However, for training purposes, I suggest you try option 2 first, and then try option 1.

Comment: By the way, if you find this answer useful, up-vote it and/or accept it ;) (oh, you've already up-voted it)